# Node.js - Wait for function to finish, then process further

Tags: node.js

I am using node.js (with express.js), I want that function first execute fully then script will execute.
I have this code,

```
var reg = register(otp)
if(reg.error){
return res.json(error:true,message:reg.message);
}
```

Where register(otp) is a function return json object
like {error:true,message:'User is already registered'}

When I run the code it logs an error,
Cannot read error property of undefined.

What to do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register must be doing something async. I think you first need to understand how asynchronous programming works in JavaScript. Check out this article for more details https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-async-programming-in-node-js/

Comment: Thanks, I will surely go through with async tutorial on web especially on youtube. BTW I want to upvote but I can't since I have 10 reputation points. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You can use callback for that async. This way it'll run only when you register function has completed.

```
var reg = register(otp, x=> {
if(x.error){
return res.json(error:true,message:reg.message);
}

})

register(otp,callback) {
... your code here ...
callback(result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try! And let you know.